# Game center submission not working

Tags: ios, submit, game-center

I have an app and am trying to submit scores to game center. this is my code:

```
- (IBAction) submitScore{

NSString *show = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Note: Scores may take some time to update"];
self.note.text = show;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submitted"
                                                message:@"Your score has been submitted to the Gamecenter leaderboard"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];


array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:Path];


NSString *s = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[array count]] stringValue];
NSString *denom = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 15];;
double resultInNum;
double sdouble = [s doubleValue];
double denomdouble = [denom doubleValue];



resultInNum = sdouble/denomdouble * 100;

if(resultInNum > 0)
{
    self.currentLeaderBoard = kLeaderboardID;

    [self.gameCenterManager reportScore: resultInNum forCategory: self.currentLeaderBoard];
    Submit.enabled = NO;



}
array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:Path];



[array writeToFile:Path atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"Count: %i", [array count]);
```

}
however when i try to do it it does not submit to the leader board. there are no errors that i am receiving in the debugger, and it used to work until i added more than one leader board. whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Score value must be an int64_t.

And I don't get why you are using NSStrings instead of directly assigning values?

Comment: i made it an int64_t but it still doesnt work and i dont know why i used nsstrings

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you do the correct code for submitting the score. This is a way that I really like. Even though you will get warnings because they don't want you to use it in iOS 7, it still works. Just let me know if it doesn't work.

`(IBAction)submitscoretogamecenter{`

```
GKLocalPlayer *localplayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localplayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

}];
//This is the same category id you set in your itunes connect GameCenter LeaderBoard
GKScore *myScoreValue = [[[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"insertCategory"] autorelease];
myScoreValue.value = scoreInt;

[myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){

    //insert what happens after it's posted 

}];
[self checkAchievements];
```

`}`